# Disabled CACHE on laravel form before edit (crome and safari browser)

Tags: laravel, forms, apache, cache-control

I have a bug  with a edit form on laravel 6

example I want edit a data
name of "test cache test 66666" to  " name cache surname cache"

and **Estado** "Seducir" to "Covencer"

[image]

100% work edit form an redirect to index

[image]

but when got again to route edit

on the form no apply change, I  check the web NOT request to my server and only charge cache view on my browser

[image]

I need press "F5" to see edit
[image]

I tried with .htcaccess

Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires 0

and with this meta header

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-store" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

I try too with form autocomplete='off'

And no result

I check and I need force browser to send request to mi serve and dont use cache browser

how can I do that?

this is the code

```
       /// dd($request->input());

    $leadsId=base64_decode($request->input('leadsId'));
    $moduleIns = ZCRMRestClient::getInstance()->getModuleInstance("Leads"); 
    
    $records = array();
    $record = ZCRMRecord::getInstance("Leads", $leadsId);
    $record->setFieldValue("First_Name", $request->input('First_Name'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Last_Name", $request->input('Last_Name'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Company", $request->input('Company'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Designation", $request->input('Designation'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Industry", $request->input('Industry'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Lead_Status", $request->input('Lead_Status'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Typo_de_Lead", $request->input('Typo_de_Lead'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Marca", $request->input('Marca'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Dealer", $request->input('Dealer'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Producto", $request->input('Producto'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Nombre_de_vendedor_de_dealer", $request->input('Nombre_de_vendedor_de_dealer'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Rep", $request->input('Rep'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Representante_email", $request->input('Representante_email'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Phone", $request->input('Phone'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Website", $request->input('Website'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Mobile", $request->input('Mobile'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Skype_ID", $request->input('Skype_ID'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Email", $request->input('Email'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Secondary_Email", $request->input('Secondary_Email'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Nombre_de_Arquitecto", $request->input('Nombre_de_Arquitecto'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Email_Arquitecto", $request->input('Email_Arquitecto'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Apellido_de_Arquitecto", $request->input('Apellido_de_Arquitecto'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Phone_Arquitecto", $request->input('Phone_Arquitecto'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Country", $request->input('Country'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Street", $request->input('Street'));
    $record->setFieldValue("City", $request->input('City'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Zip_Code", $request->input('Zip_Code'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Estado", $request->input('Estado'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Showroom_Ciudad", $request->input('Showroom_Ciudad'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Fecha_de_cooking_demo",$this->FechaZoho($request->input('Fecha_de_cooking_demo')));
    $record->setFieldValue("Fecha_de_visita_al_Showroom", $this->FechaZoho($request->input('Fecha_de_visita_al_Showroom')));
    $record->setFieldValue("Description", $request->input('Description'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Estado_de_Prospecto", $request->input('Estado_de_Prospecto'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Hora_de_visita_al_showroom", $request->input('Hora_de_visita_al_showroom'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Hora_de_la_llamada", $request->input('Hora_de_la_llamada'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Fecha_de_la_llamada", $this->FechaZoho($request->input('Fecha_de_la_llamada')));
    $record->setFieldValue("UTM_Source", $request->input('UTM_Source'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Lead_Source", $request->input('Lead_Source'));
    $record->setFieldValue("UTM_Anuncio_ID", $request->input('UTM_Anuncio_ID'));
    $record->setFieldValue("UTM_Campaign_Name", $request->input('UTM_Campaign_Name'));
    $record->setFieldValue("Creado_Desde_Admin_Web", true);


    //dd($record);
    
    array_push($records, $record); // pushing the record to the array
   // $duplicate_check_fields=array('Company');
    $lar_id=null; // THIS LINE
    $trigger=array();//trigger to include
    $responseIn = $moduleIns->updateRecords($records,null,$lar_id,null); 

    $zohoRespuesta=$responseIn->getEntityResponses();
   // dd($zohoRespuesta);
    
    if($zohoRespuesta[0]->getStatus()!='success'){
       abort(404);
    }

        /******* SALES MANAGO ************/
        $var=new SalesManago();
        $var->setSmEmail($request->input('Email'));
        $var->setEstado($request->input('Estado'));
        $var->setSmNombre($request->input('First_Name')." ".$request->input('Last_Name'));
        $var->setTag($this->asignarTagSM ($request->input('Lead_Status')));
        $var->setSmPhone($request->input('Phone'));
        $var->setProducto($request->input('Producto'));
        $var->setMensaje($request->input('Description'));
        $var->setBrand((!empty($request->input('Marca'))) ? implode(",", $request->input('Marca')) : '');
        //dd($var);
        $response=$var->upsert();


        $varArq=new SalesManago();
        $varArq->setSmNombre($request->input('Nombre_de_Arquitecto'));
        $varArq->setSmPhone($request->input('Phone_Arquitecto'));
        $varArq->setSmEmail($request->input('Email_Arquitecto'));
        $varArq->setTag('ARQUITECTO');
        $response=$varArq->upsert();
        /******* SALES MANAGO ************/
        
        $response=$varArq->upsert();
        /******* SALES MANAGO ************/

      $notification = array(
                        'message'    => trans('global.stored_record'), 
                        'alert_type' => 'success'
                    );
    
    

    \Session::flash('notification', $notification);

    //return redirect()->route('admin.leads.index');
    return redirect()->back();
    // dd($request->input('leadsId'));
    //return redirect()->route('admin.deals.edit', ['leadsId'=>urldecode($request->input('leadsId'))]);
```

Comment: I don't think this is a cache issue - please show your save method where you 'redirect'

Comment: yes, if cache because if I clear  the method update o i put a dd() or die helper intencionaly,  and save the change the app  no take this change and show the old data

Comment: change your cache driver in your .env to 'file', but share some code, I'm still hesitant on believing that cache is the issue

Comment: you're returning 'back', that's probably why you don't have the updated inputs... try `->refresh()` with your redirect

Comment: i put back byr moment  return to edit views and this work but the real that I need is go to index //return redirect()->route('admin.deals.index'); on index check the video and you see https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-6SCfU8JaM29mlrPU_QQidTR17JT7Hx9/view?usp=sharing